# What are "heroes in a half shell"?

Tags: teenage-mutant-ninja-turtles, teenage-mutant-ninja-turtles-1987

They say this line every time in the [*Teenage Mutant Ninja Turtles* 1987 cartoon opening.](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=AxuvUAjHYWQ)

What does heroes in a half shell really mean? A tortoise has a shell all around its body, and the teenage mutant ninja turtles seem to have the part of their shell on their back as well as on their front. Why are they heroes in a half shell?

Comment: Turtle power! (Sorry, you can't just end your question with those lyrics and not prompt that response) From wiktionary, "_Any half of a roughly spherical-like object; any dome-shaped object._"

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/half_shell

Comment: @n_b but he turtles have their full shell

Comment: I'm going to suggest poetic license. It is a kids' tv show theme song, after all. It's also possible the song writer doesn't know the bottom of a turtle is also protected by a shell.

Comment: Now I'm wondering what lyrical benefit "*half-shell*" has over "*hard shell*"...

Comment: I always took it as a poetic riff on the painting titled "Venus on the half-shell."

Answer (score 68):

This is a reference to (or pun on) the idiom "on the half shell", which is a way of serving shellfish (but not turtles). For example:

> **on the half shell**
>   of raw shellfish, served in the bottom shell, chilled and with condiments

—[Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/on-the-half-shell)

> **on the half shell**
>   served raw, with seasonings, on a half shell
>   said of oysters, etc.

—[Collins English Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/on-the-half-shell)

It seems likely to me that the writer of the theme song identified this idiom with the old-fashioned practice of serving turtle soup in the turtle's shell. For example:

> Accounts in the 18th and 19th centuries of massive parties known as “turtle frolics” suggest they were more popular than hog barbecues and oyster roasts, with descriptions of servants bearing three-foot-long upturned turtle shells filled with hot turtle stew for large crowds.

—Jack Hitt, [What Ever Happened to Turtle Soup?](http://www.saveur.com/history-of-turtle-soup-hunting), Saveur, 2015

Since Shredder often [vowed to turn the Ninja Turtles into turtle soup](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HvHFlt3bipA), it seems likely to me that the two culinary references are related. While the idiom "on the half shell" is not applied to turtle cuisine in real life, turtle soup served in the upper part of the turtle's shell would indeed be "in a half shell" in literal terms. So, to me, the line is effectively winking at Shredder's failed threat that he would dine on soup made of his enemies.

Comment: Sorry seems a bit far-fetched to me... Reminded me of my highschool English teacher who sought the most far-fetched social symbolism in the literature we had to read

Comment: @nluigi But this isn't science; the most logically simple answer is not the correct one.  This song-lyric and story-writing art, where any answer that could make sense to the audiences at the time is a good answer.  So recognizer is completely correct; but there may be additional correct answer too.  It seems your literature teachers failed to teach you that basic principle of art: that the spectrum of understandings that any and all audience members will have is the point.

Comment: @SlippD.Thompson - On the contrary, in this case the most logical and simple answer *is* the correct one. And this is the most simple answer. On this site, we generally do believe in a single correct answer, and do our best to discern the author’s intent. Sometimes, of course, it isn’t clear…but this doesn’t appear to be one of those times.

Comment: And if there’s a *purpose* for most art, it’s probably to make money, no?

Comment: @Adamant Sorry, that's not how art works. If there is a “correct” answer, it would be up to the writers of the song and them alone. Unless you can find a quote from them, you can't define any answer as _the correct_ answer. But as a whole, art is subjective; any applicable solution is correct. This SE Answer covers 1 solution, and other answers below cover other solutions.  Considering how likely it is that the lyric is a pun, it's plausible that all of the solutions brought up in the SE Answers here were all intended by the author.

Comment: @SlippD.Thompson - That is, indeed, why we frequently seek out quotes from authors, and consider them among the highest-quality answers. We generally views answers *without* authorial confirmation (the majority) as attempts, often very good ones, to get at what the author meant.

Comment: @Adamant No. The purpose of art is to covey emotions.

Comment: If there’s a *purpose* for most art, it’s to make money, no? I’ve always found some merit in the anti-colonialist critiques of *l’art pour l’art* as lacking an understanding of the varied purposes that “art” objects have served throughout history and across cultures. Art certainly *can* have the purpose of conveying emotions, but that can also be incidental, or even pragmatic. If we take any object or performance that *incidentally* produces emotions as art, of course, we are led to absurdity - wherein, say, Donald Trump’s presidency is a great work of art because it inspires anger.

Comment: @Adamant Okay, I think what I've written is a bit confusing here.  In all of the above, when I say “answer” or “solution” I mean it in the general sense.  When I say “SE Answer”, I mean specific posts here on Stack Exchange.

Comment: Likely a bit overthinking.   Very likely they simply looked for turtle related phrasing or puns, came across "on the half shell", said "Hey turtles have shells!" and stuck it in the song.   So very likely the "half" part of it has no actual reference to the show.

Comment: @SlippD.Thompson Yes, the purpose of the art is up to the author.  But the author isn't always standing there to be interviewed.  So good authors generally like to make sure that the audience can figure it out themselves.

Comment: @MishaRosnach Exactly.

Comment: I think the phrase comes from the way of serving food, but I don't think it had anything to do with shredder and turtle soup.

Comment: Even as a 10 year old I thought the meaning of the lyrics was pretty obviously this. I'm a bit surprised there's any dispute.

Comment: I think any artist will agree that if we want to make money, there are easier ways. We choose to make art because we are driven to. If we are able to make money at it, all the better, but a purely economic rationale for the creation of art is ridiculous.

Answer (score 29):

Their shell doesn't go all the way around their body though, at least not in this show.  Look:

[image]

This is from this same theme song.  They have some yellow shell-type surface in the front, but it isn't connected to what is clearly a half-shell on their back.

Comment: I always thought the reason they looked like this in the cartoon was only for aesthetic purposes and they were supposed to have their full shells. After all, they have the ability to hide inside their shells in the movie

Comment: @user13267 I've never seen the movie, but I'm guessing it doesn't sing about them being on a half-shell :)  Plus there is more than one movie.  Here is a shot from the 2016 movie (http://frontrowcentral.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/IMG_1304.png), where they have the same shell type.  I think it's perfectly possible that the animated series' character artist's reasoning for the design was aesthetic.  Plus there is the shellfish / soup joke.  But, in the end, that's the character design,

Answer (score 11):

The best explanation I can offer is that regular turtles can withdraw their bodies into their shells to virtually eliminate all exposure

[image]

Since the TMNT are more humanoid, they can't do this. So they have a shell that essentially protects half their body. A "half shell", if you will

Comment: aren't  the supposed to be able to inside their shells?

Comment: @user13267 Seems to [depend on what version you're talking about](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/76994/can-the-turtles-go-inside-their-shells). While there's some visual gags with it, the most they seem to be able to do is withdraw their heads. I don't recall them doing it to protect their limbs (but, then again, kids shows don't show cuts or blood)

Comment: they did it in the movie I think, but did they ever do that in the cartoon?

Comment: Some people in the other question said they did but I can't find any images, nor do I recall any original series doing so. The more modern cartoons have.

Comment: The turtle in this picture has a half-shell, plus a breastplate sort of thing.  A turtle with a full shell (i.e., a spherical one) wouldn't be able to walk, not unless it had very long legs.

Comment: @HarryJohnston What? The turtle in the picture has a full shell. There is no such thing as a spherical shell turtle

Comment: @Machavity, a turtle's shell can be described either as a shell *or* as a [half shell](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/half_shell) - English is funny that way.  The phrase "half shell" doesn't mean "half of the amount of shell that is normal for turtles" it means "forming half of a sphere".

Answer (score 2):

Biology aside, I'm pretty sure the lyrics are just a nod to the existing hipness of the surfer/skateboard culture at the time (late 80's) where the use of surfer slang is spreading by the kids/turtles.

> bummer", "dude", "bogus", "radical", "far-out", "tubuloso", "bodacious", and possibly the most recognized, "cowabunga"

These catch-words are surfer slang.

The phrase "heroes in a half-shell" is their way of incorporating this culture (or being a part of it) in replacing "half-pipe" with "half-shell".

TL;DR version: It's cool and hip jive from the late 80's.

Answer (score -2):

I think that the reference "heroes in a half shell” refers to their mutation, being half humanoid and half turtle.